# Unable to save applescripts-created email in drafts folder in Outlook version 16

Tags: outlook, applescript

So I've been using applescript with Outlook version 16 to automate some tasks. I want to create an email and then save it in the drafts folder but i've been unsuccessful.

I've tried several variations on this (like save newMessage in drafts, etc.) but can't seem to get it to work - dictionary for applescript/outlook hasn't been too helpful either. Perhaps I'm not experienced enough to understand it... I can open the email I create. I can send it from outlook. I just can't save it in drafts.

```
tell application "Microsoft Outlook"

    set newMessage to make new outgoing message with properties {subject:"Hello I'm an email"}

    set plain text content of newMessage to "Hello World "

    save in drafts

end tell
```